# cordova inappbrowser system hidden

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I used cordova Inappbrowser plugin

options _system and hidden=yes but it didn't work

options _blank and hidden=yes is success

In _system option don't hide the browser?

Comment: Clarify your question!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below method for inappbrowser.

```
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';  // on TOP

In your constructor

private iab: InAppBrowser

this.iab.create(url);  // Add this in your code. This will open third party 
url in your browser.
```